# How to add three dots menu in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin. 
I want to add a context menu (something like three dots as shown in the below image) in my app. The menu must be displayed when I tap on the three dots image which is present inside a ListView's ItemTemplate.

Below is kind of start what I expect. How can I achieve this requirement in Xamarin?

Any help on this would be highly helpful.

[image]

Comment: ,According to your screenshot, you want to add menu for every ListView item? I have saw you have add toolbar item for contentpage.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#context-actions

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can either use the context menu for conventional behaviors if you expecting or you can use open source popups to customize if your requirement is complex.

> If you are new to Xamarin, then I would recommend you to go with the first approach.

**Approach 1:**

Refer the [documentation here for the context menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#context-actions) in ListView.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem) will be more helpful.

You have to do something like below.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Share"
                                    IconImageSource="share.png"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.ShareCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    <MenuItem Text="Add to playlist"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.AddToPlaylistCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <Grid>
                    ...
                    <Image Source="ThreeDottedIcon" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ThreeDottedIconPopup}"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

> Note: You have to write your view model logic based on your requirement which I have not given here.

**Approach 2**

Otherwise, if you wish to use opensource popups, then there is an [opensource plugin](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) to configure this.

The below code example just works fine for me.

**XAML Page**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            ...
            <Image Source="ThreeDottedIcon" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ThreeDottedIconPopup}"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**XAML.cs page**

```
private Command _threeDottedIconPopup;
public Command ThreeDottedIconPopup
{
    get
    {
        return _threeDottedIconPopup?? (_threeDottedIconPopup= new Command(async () =>
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new ContextPopup(ParametersIfRequired));
        }));
    }
}
```

> Refer to the [link here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup/) for the NuGet packages for the Popup.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am not expect that

Comment: see image abocve

Comment: Your question was totally misleading asking for context menu earlier. I have edited my answer now. Please check.

Comment: Hi I need something like this but just wondering is this Plugin Popup Lazy Loaded? My app loding  time is almost approaching 2 seconds!!